# Netlify Front-End displaying CORS error when requesting data from Heroku back-end

Tags: heroku, axios, cors, netlify

Update:

I currently have a front-end deployed via Netlify, my back-end deployed via Heroku, and MongoDB via Atlas. I had no issues when hosting locally and when I deployed my back-end, I sent requests via postman which also returned perfect.

Upon attempting to login via my front-end, I was getting denied via cross origin, so I installed the CORS middleware and placed it in my index.js file:

```
app.use(cors());

// Express Parsing Middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// SESSION SETUP
const sessionStore = MongoStore.create({
  mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URL,
});

console.log("MongoDB: " + process.env.MONGO_URL);
console.log("Secret " + process.env.SECRET);

// Express Use Session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  })
);

// Passport Auth Middleware
require("./config/passport");

// Initialize Passport and Use Session for Serialize/Deserialization
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/*app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.session);
  console.log(req.user);
  next();
});*/

// Debugger
app.use(morgan("common"));

/*
          ==========
          ==ROUTES==
          ==========
*/

// User Route
app.use("/api", loginRoute);
```

This did not fix the cross origin issues, so while attempting to fix it I removed the withCredentials: attribute from my axios instances on my front-end, which now seems to work, but instead of routing me to /api/login and routing to either login-success or login-failure depending on if the credentials are right, it goes to /login then to /login-success before suddenly routing to /protected-route and throwing a 401, which it shouldn't and didn't before.

I also noticed that the session cookie that was stored before in the browser when it was hosted locally appears to not be storing there. This is handled via passportJS.

```
const axios = require("axios");

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://***.herokuapp.com/api/",
  timeout: 1000,
  withCredentials: false,
});
```

I'm not entirely sure why any of this is happening, but if I can get some insight I would appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Issue was fixed by setting cors options to `credentials: true`

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "https://****.netlify.app",
  credentials: true,
};
```

`app.use(cors(corsOptions));`